# Practical Python-based visual programming environment?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am looking for a practical visual programming environment based on Python.  My primary application is algorithm development for processing remote-sensing imagery.  I was initially inspired by LabVIEW from National Instruments, but that is more geared towards laboratory measurements and simulations.  I write a lot of prototype code in Python and do a lot of interactive analysis with IPython.

Does there exist a visual framework where a "program" is represented by connected nodes which each read data, do some work, and output data to the next node?  I would like to use Python to write the code residing in each node.

So far the best I've seen is Orange http://www.ailab.si/orange/, but it does not have the ability to start/stop individual nodes.

Comment: I have now also come across the VisTrails http://www.vistrails.org/index.php/Main_Page package that is more closely related to what I'm looking for.  Its a scientific workflow environment based on Python.  I'm going to try it out tonight.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Ryven: "A simple flow-based visual scripting runtime environment for Python"
https://github.com/leon-thomm/Ryven

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out VISION

http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=7430000&fromSeriesID=743

Comment: I downloaded VISION from here: https://www.osc.edu/cms/sip/node/5 and I had some trouble.  This package installs its own self-contained Python environment.  When I tried to run it I got an error message saying python.exe was making an inappropriate call to a C runtime.  Btw, my system is running Windows 7 x64.

So then I looked around and downloaded the Python source and managed to get that to work.  The overall interface is kludgy and unappealing.  As for getting the job done, I give it a solid "maybe".  Each Node is a Python object method editable in real time.  , which is a plus for me.

Comment: yes, I think the installer is out of date, especially for 64-bit systems. the upside is that it is a pure-Python solution. I know it's ugly, but it doesn't require installing a separate GUI library. Additionally, you might want to post to the Scripps (i.e. VISION developers) mailing list about this. They might have other ideas.

Comment: The site is down now